# Python - replacing specific numbers in a list

Tags: python, list

I have scores from a questionnaire:

```
list= [1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Certain questions need to be reverse-scored.
"Rscores" is the list of indexes that need to be reverse-scored, this means that for those scores, if it's 1, then it needs to be replaced with a 4 and if it's a 2, it needs to be replaced with a 3.

```
Rscores = [1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 28, 33, 38, 43, 49, 57, 8, 46, 2, 7, 12, 17, 22, 25, 35, 40]
```

I have tried this, and many variations of it, but it doesn't work:

```
for Rscores in list:
    if list[Rscores] == 1:
        list[Rscores] = 4
    elif list[Rscores] == 2:
        list[Rscores] = 3
    elif list[Rscores] == 3:
        list[Rscores] = 2
    elif list[Rscores] == 4:
        list[Rscores] = 1
```

If anyone can help, I would be very grateful.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `for Rscores in list:` Nope, you want the idx which are in `Rscores`. 1. Do not name a variable `list`, chagne this to `L` for instance. `list` is a build-in function. 2. Change the for loop with `for idx in Rscores` and then chante all the `[Rscores]` with `[idx]`

Comment: Note that computing the reverse score is just 5-score.

Comment: you can make a for loop on the Rscores  and check if the index on your list and change your list: for i in Rscores: if list[i]==1: etc.... In any case if you run it with your example it will fail because your list len is 42 and in Rscores you have values bigger than 42, so it will fail for "list index out of range"

Comment: @Carlo1585: This is it!  the for i in rscores if list==1.... Thank you

Comment: You're welcome ;)

Comment: You appear to have accepted an answer that completely ignores the `Rscores` list, which I find a little strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it;s working

```
list= [1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3]

for n, i in enumerate(list):
    if i == 1:
        list[n] = 4
    if i == 2:
        list[n] = 3
    if i == 3:
        list[n] = 2
    if i == 4:
        list[n] = 1
print(list)
```

Hope it's help full

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This creates a new list, with the necessary scores rectified.

```
lst= [1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4,
      3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4, 1,
      2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3]

Rscores = [1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 28, 33, 38, 43, 49, 57,
           8, 46, 2, 7, 12, 17, 22, 25, 35, 40]

rectified_scores = [5-x if i in Rscores else x for i, x in enumerate(lst)]
```

`enumerate` yields a sequence of pairs (i, x), where `i` is the element index and `x` is its value. `5-x if i in Rscores else x` is the score for a standard index, and the inverse of the score for indexes in the `Rscores` list.

I renamed your list to avoid "shadowing" the name of a Python type. Your code would probably run marginally faster if `Rscores` were a set, but it's not screaming to be optimised.

Answer (score 0):

```py
L = [1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3]
Rscores = [1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 28, 33, 38, 43, 49, 57, 8, 46, 2, 7, 12, 17, 22, 25, 35, 40]

def reverseScore(score):
    if score == 1:
        return 4
    elif score == 2:
        return 3
    elif score == 3:
        return 2
    elif score == 4:
        return 1

def rscoredList(L):
    for idx in Rscores:
        if idx < len(L):
            L[idx] = reverseScore(L[idx])
    return L

L = rscoredList(L)
```

I think a problem in the example you listed is that you have indices in your `Rscores` that are outside the range of your list. (57 is listed as a to be reversed index tho it can't be because `len(L)==42`.)